# How to solve Apache 2.4 mod_rewrite adding unnecessary and unwanted path info postfix?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Relevant parts of .htaccess: (all others commented out)

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /somesite/

...

# All non-directory requests should go to /web/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(web|cms|shared)/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1

...

# Language is irrelevant for resource passthrough. Strip it.
RewriteRule ^web/(en|nl)/(.*)$ web/$2

...
```

To keep the case simple, all unshown stuff is also commented out, so it does not affect the case.

Request:
`http://some.domain.com/somesite/en/projecten/img/logo.png`

Ends up:
`http://some.domain.com/somesite/web/projecten/img/logo.png/projecten/img/logo.png`

Though at this point, it should be:
`http://some.domain.com/somesite/web/projecten/img/logo.png`

In the logs, I traced the problem to a `trace3` line stating `add path info postfix:`, which basically adds the unwanted part. This line is located directly after the first matching rewrite was performed. Everything happens within the same processing pass.

These are my only two rules that are chained, i.e. not final results and thus do not have the `L`-flag. This seems to be related to the problem.

Can someone enlighten me on what is happening, why, and an efficient solution?

Thanks in advance!

*EDIT:*
For the record the complete log related to this request:

```
[rewrite:trace3] - - [dev.company.nl/sid#17962b0][rid#1a88ce0/initial] [perdir /home/dev/domains/dev.company.nl/public_html/company_website/] add path info postfix: /home/dev/domains/dev.company.nl/public_html/company_website/en -> /home/dev/domains/dev.company.nl/public_html/company_website/en/projecten/img/company_logo.png
[rewrite:trace3] - - [dev.company.nl/sid#17962b0][rid#1a88ce0/initial] [perdir /home/dev/domains/dev.company.nl/public_html/company_website/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/dev/domains/dev.company.nl/public_html/company_website/en/projecten/img/company_logo.png -> en/projecten/img/company_logo.png
[rewrite:trace3] - - [dev.company.nl/sid#17962b0][rid#1a88ce0/initial] [perdir /home/dev/domains/dev.company.nl/public_html/company_website/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'en/projecten/img/company_logo.png'
[rewrite:trace4] - - [dev.company.nl/sid#17962b0][rid#1a88ce0/initial] [perdir /home/dev/domains/dev.company.nl/public_html/company_website/] RewriteCond: input='/company_website/en/projecten/img/company_logo.png' pattern='!/(web|cms|shared)/.*$' => matched
[rewrite:trace2] - - [dev.company.nl/sid#17962b0][rid#1a88ce0/initial] [perdir /home/dev/domains/dev.company.nl/public_html/company_website/] rewrite 'en/projecten/img/company_logo.png' -> 'web/en/projecten/img/company_logo.png'
[rewrite:trace3] - - [dev.company.nl/sid#17962b0][rid#1a88ce0/initial] [perdir /home/dev/domains/dev.company.nl/public_html/company_website/] add per-dir prefix: web/en/projecten/img/company_logo.png -> /home/dev/domains/dev.company.nl/public_html/company_website/web/en/projecten/img/company_logo.png
[rewrite:trace3] - - [dev.company.nl/sid#17962b0][rid#1a88ce0/initial] [perdir /home/dev/domains/dev.company.nl/public_html/company_website/] add path info postfix: /home/dev/domains/dev.company.nl/public_html/company_website/web/en/projecten/img/company_logo.png -> /home/dev/domains/dev.company.nl/public_html/company_website/web/en/projecten/img/company_logo.png/projecten/img/company_logo.png
[rewrite:trace3] - - [dev.company.nl/sid#17962b0][rid#1a88ce0/initial] [perdir /home/dev/domains/dev.company.nl/public_html/company_website/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/dev/domains/dev.company.nl/public_html/company_website/web/en/projecten/img/company_logo.png/projecten/img/company_logo.png -> web/en/projecten/img/company_logo.png/projecten/img/company_logo.png
[rewrite:trace3] - - [dev.company.nl/sid#17962b0][rid#1a88ce0/initial] [perdir /home/dev/domains/dev.company.nl/public_html/company_website/] applying pattern '^web/(en|nl)/(.*)$' to uri 'web/en/projecten/img/company_logo.png/projecten/img/company_logo.png'
[rewrite:trace2] - - [dev.company.nl/sid#17962b0][rid#1a88ce0/initial] [perdir /home/dev/domains/dev.company.nl/public_html/company_website/] rewrite 'web/en/projecten/img/company_logo.png/projecten/img/company_logo.png' -> 'web/projecten/img/company_logo.png/projecten/img/company_logo.png'
[rewrite:trace3] - - [dev.company.nl/sid#17962b0][rid#1a88ce0/initial] [perdir /home/dev/domains/dev.company.nl/public_html/company_website/] add per-dir prefix: web/projecten/img/company_logo.png/projecten/img/company_logo.png -> /home/dev/domains/dev.company.nl/public_html/company_website/web/projecten/img/company_logo.png/projecten/img/company_logo.png
[rewrite:trace2] - - [dev.company.nl/sid#17962b0][rid#1a88ce0/initial] [perdir /home/dev/domains/dev.company.nl/public_html/company_website/] trying to replace prefix /home/dev/domains/dev.company.nl/public_html/company_website/ with /company_website/
[rewrite:trace5] - - [dev.company.nl/sid#17962b0][rid#1a88ce0/initial] strip matching prefix: /home/dev/domains/dev.company.nl/public_html/company_website/web/projecten/img/company_logo.png/projecten/img/company_logo.png -> web/projecten/img/company_logo.png/projecten/img/company_logo.png
[rewrite:trace4] - - [dev.company.nl/sid#17962b0][rid#1a88ce0/initial] add subst prefix: web/projecten/img/company_logo.png/projecten/img/company_logo.png -> /company_website/web/projecten/img/company_logo.png/projecten/img/company_logo.png
[rewrite:trace1] - - [dev.company.nl/sid#17962b0][rid#1a88ce0/initial] [perdir /home/dev/domains/dev.company.nl/public_html/company_website/] internal redirect with /company_website/web/projecten/img/company_logo.png/projecten/img/company_logo.png [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[rewrite:trace3] - - [dev.company.nl/sid#17962b0][rid#1a95a20/initial/redir#1] [perdir /home/dev/domains/dev.company.nl/public_html/company_website/] add path info postfix: /home/dev/domains/dev.company.nl/public_html/company_website/web/projecten -> /home/dev/domains/dev.company.nl/public_html/company_website/web/projecten/img/company_logo.png/projecten/img/company_logo.png
[rewrite:trace3] - - [dev.company.nl/sid#17962b0][rid#1a95a20/initial/redir#1] [perdir /home/dev/domains/dev.company.nl/public_html/company_website/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/dev/domains/dev.company.nl/public_html/company_website/web/projecten/img/company_logo.png/projecten/img/company_logo.png -> web/projecten/img/company_logo.png/projecten/img/company_logo.png
[rewrite:trace3] - - [dev.company.nl/sid#17962b0][rid#1a95a20/initial/redir#1] [perdir /home/dev/domains/dev.company.nl/public_html/company_website/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'web/projecten/img/company_logo.png/projecten/img/company_logo.png'
[rewrite:trace4] - - [dev.company.nl/sid#17962b0][rid#1a95a20/initial/redir#1] [perdir /home/dev/domains/dev.company.nl/public_html/company_website/] RewriteCond: input='/company_website/web/projecten/img/company_logo.png/projecten/img/company_logo.png' pattern='!/(web|cms|shared)/.*$' => not-matched
[rewrite:trace3] - - [dev.company.nl/sid#17962b0][rid#1a95a20/initial/redir#1] [perdir /home/dev/domains/dev.company.nl/public_html/company_website/] add path info postfix: /home/dev/domains/dev.company.nl/public_html/company_website/web/projecten -> /home/dev/domains/dev.company.nl/public_html/company_website/web/projecten/img/company_logo.png/projecten/img/company_logo.png
[rewrite:trace3] - - [dev.company.nl/sid#17962b0][rid#1a95a20/initial/redir#1] [perdir /home/dev/domains/dev.company.nl/public_html/company_website/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/dev/domains/dev.company.nl/public_html/company_website/web/projecten/img/company_logo.png/projecten/img/company_logo.png -> web/projecten/img/company_logo.png/projecten/img/company_logo.png
[rewrite:trace3] - - [dev.company.nl/sid#17962b0][rid#1a95a20/initial/redir#1] [perdir /home/dev/domains/dev.company.nl/public_html/company_website/] applying pattern '^web/(en|nl)/(.*)$' to uri 'web/projecten/img/company_logo.png/projecten/img/company_logo.png'
[rewrite:trace1] - - [dev.company.nl/sid#17962b0][rid#1a95a20/initial/redir#1] [perdir /home/dev/domains/dev.company.nl/public_html/company_website/] pass through /home/dev/domains/dev.company.nl/public_html/company_website/web/projecten
```

Comment: try `DPI`-flag http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_dpi

Comment: Thanks. Adding it to both rules, or, in other words, adding it to all rules that did not have the `L`-flag in my case, solved the problem. Could you write an answer explaining what happens and why it happens, so we can understand when to use it next time? The Apache documentation is not all too clear sometimes. If you do, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: See [`AcceptPathInfo`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo). Apache may detect `<real file path>+PATH_INFO` after each mod_rewrite processing and then discard that `PATH_INFO` before next rule. Resulting path may contain multi appended `PATH_INFO`, calculated during mod_rewrite processing.